# Error: Missing expected firebase config value databaseURL, when hit firebase deploy command

Tags: node.js, database, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Error: Missing expected firebase config value databaseURL, config is actually

```
{
  "projectId":"app-production",
  "storageBucket":"app-production.appspot.com",
  "locationId":"asia-south1"
}
```

If you are unit testing, please set process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG

when hit `firebase deploy` command

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems pretty clear: you need to add a `databaseURL` property to your configuration snippet. They are typically of the form `app-production.firebaseio.com`, so you might want to start with that:

```
{
  "projectId":"app-production",
  "storageBucket":"app-production.appspot.com",
  "locationId":"asia-south1",
  "databaseURL":"https://app-production.firebaseio.com"
}
```

Comment: I just fixed issue by setup realtime database in firebase console. In my cloud function nodejs code,, i wrongly refer realtime database.